# How to create a new column with a custom cluster name according to the value of clv score, K-Means Clustering

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This is the following DataFrame I have

| Cluster | CLV Score |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 571,038 |
| 3 | 1,474,358 |
| 1 | 568,211 |

Since the context of the table was about customer segmentation
I wanted to create a new column that contains the name of each cluster based on the clv score
another thing to account is that the user can be changed by the user

the output would look like this

| Cluster | CLV Score | Cluster Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 1,474,358 | Gold Customer |
| 1 | 571,038 | Silver Customer |
| 3 | 568,211 | Dormant Customer |

Any help or explanation are very appreciate
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a job for [`pd.cut()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html):

```py
>>> df.assign(cluster_name=pd.cut(df['CLV Score'], bins=3,
...                               labels=['Dormant', 'Silver', 'Gold']))
         CLV Score cluster_name
Cluster                        
2           571038      Dormant
3          1474358         Gold
1           568211      Dormant
```

You can of course customize the bin edges:

```py
>>> df.assign(cluster_name=pd.cut(
...     df['CLV Score'], bins=[0, 0.57e6, 1e6, float('inf')],
...     labels=['Dormant', 'Silver', 'Gold']))
         CLV Score cluster_name
Cluster                        
2           571038       Silver
3          1474358         Gold
1           568211      Dormant
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use numpy (nested) to check if the scores are between certain values and set that to a column.

```py
df["Cluster Name"] = np.where(
  df["CLV Score"] < 570000, "Dormant Customer",
    np.where(df["CLV Score"] < 1400000, "Silver Customer", "Gold Customer")
)
```